# making my own /dev/random, buffer not working, c

Tags: c, random, buffer, driver, device

i have to make a device driver that returns a random number between 1 - 50 and am confused on how the buffer for my device driver works, and how to go about getting it to behave like /dev/random.

i made a test program to see how /dev/random works:

```
int test_read = open("/dev/random", O_RDONLY);
int get_random_num(void) {

  unsigned int random_num;
  read(test_read, &random_num, sizeof(random_num));
  return (random_num % 50) + 1;
}
```

and then this is my device driver's read function(concised version):

```
my_random_read(struct file* file, char* buf,
                      size_t count, loff_t* ppos)
{
    unsigned int random_num; 
    get_random_bytes(&random_num, 1);
    int my_num = 1 + (random_num % 50)

    int* my_num_pointer = &my_num;

    copy_to_user(buf, my_num_pointer, count);
}
```

when i run my tester on QEMU i get -1074311964 : /

how can i make it so that all i would have to do is replace /dev/random with /dev/my_random??

this is how i'm reading from /dev/my_random:

```
    read(test_read, &random_number, sizeof(random_number), 0);
```

Comment: I don't understand the question.  You've posted a code snippet, then you ask how to emulate `/dev/random`, but your question title implies there's a bug.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth after i compile and load my device driver (where the code snippet is from), i read from /dev/my_random and what's returned is -1074311964.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
unsigned int random_num; 
get_random_bytes(&random_num, 1);
```

You're using `get_random_bytes()` incorrectly. The second parameter is the number of bytes, not words:

```
void get_random_bytes(void *buf, int nbytes)
```

You're further returning **private kernel memory** to userspace:

```
my_random_read(struct file* file, char* buf,
                      size_t count, loff_t* ppos)
{
    /* ... */
    int* my_num_pointer = &my_num;
    copy_to_user(buf, my_num_pointer, count);
}
```

You've performed *no* validations on `count` -- you only have one, maybe two, bytes of actual random data here. The rest of the data is garbage stack data and you've leaked it to userspace here. This is a **security flaw** -- the kernel should not leak uninitialized data to userspace. (It might be garbage to rely on it yourself but an attacker that asks for ten pages of data from `/dev/random` should not get raw kernel memory.)

Comment: thanks for the response. i'll try using sizeof() in get_random_bytes and limit count to 1.

Comment: You won't want to limit `count` to `1`, either, as that is just one byte. `sizeof` is probably the better answer.

Comment: ok i made the changes and put a printk after: int my_num = 1 + (random_num % 50) and it's printing out a a number between 1 and 50, but the user space tester program is still printing out garbage like -1079978156

Comment: Is `random_card` also an `unsigned int`?

Comment: hmm i tried both, signed and unsigned but it still didn't work. passing an int* to a char* buffer is legal??

Comment: Yes, the `char *` is the only byte-wise interface that can handle any kind of data. Maybe edit your question to include the updated test and updated driver?

Comment: @Tim: please add an answer with the fix; I'm curious and I'm sure someone else in the future will be curious too. Congrats!